# How can I determine if a file input has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a script that will trigger the click event for a file upload form. I want to be able to determine of the file upload button has already been clicked. Here is what I have:

```
<div ng-click="uploadFile()">Click Me</div>
<input name="uploader" type="file" style="display:none;">

var uploadFile = function () {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('input[name=uploader]').trigger('click');
            clearInterval(interval);
    }, 50);
}
```

The problem is that the upload button is triggered twice. The first time the file browser opens up, allowing me to select a local file to upload. But, if I hit cancel, the file browser opens back up again. I would like to place a condition in the above code that would check to see if the file upload button has already been triggered. How can I do this? Something like the following:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if(hasUploaderBeenTriggered === false) { // not sure how to do this part
        $('input[name=uploader]').trigger('click');
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need the first click or do you just want to know when the user selected their file? Otherwise you could check out onchange instead of onclick.

You can create a global variable / boolean that you switch on and off when the user clicks the button, if the user then clicks the button again you can check if the boolean is false.

Put `var hasUploaderBeenTriggered = false;` at the very top of your javascript and then add `hasUploaderBeenTriggered = true;` after `clearInterval(interval);` like so:

```
var hasUploaderBeenTriggered = false;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if(hasUploaderBeenTriggered === false) { // not sure how to do this part
        $('input[name=uploader]').trigger('click');
        clearInterval(interval);
        hasUploaderBeenTriggered = true;
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Yes, I need the first click. The actual ``input`` field is hidden from the user.

Comment: Alright, so how about making `hasUploaderBeenTriggered` a boolean. Put `var hasUploaderBeenTriggered = false;` at the very top of your javascript and then add `hasUploaderBeenTriggered = true;` after `clearInterval(interval);`